# Bootstrap gives me Multiple Select by default

Tags: html, css, laravel, laravel-blade

I have this select:

```
      <select id= "direction" name="direction" size="4" class="form-control">
            <option value="up" >Up</option>
            <option value="down">Down</option>
            <option value="right">Right</option>
            <option value="left">Left</option>
      </select>
```

Which gives me a multiple selector like the second example [here](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_form_select&stacked=h). However I want it to be a normal dropdown like in the first example. There is clearly no multiple in the select.

Any ideas?

Comment: Just noticed it is because of the size="4" by the way.

Comment: Remove the size attribute .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change `size="4"` to `size="1"`.

Comment: Or just remove `size`.

Answer (score 1):

```
<select multiple class="form-control" id="sel2">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
  </select>
```

Add "multiple" attribute